# How to return REST API response after utility execution is finished in expressJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, setinterval, es6-promise

I have written one POST endpoint in expressJS with node.when I a make call to API It runs a utility with setInterval() and I want to send the API response after utility executes clearInterval().
How I can I wait and send response after utility execution is finished?
Please see the code below

REST API code:

```
const router= express.Router();
const multer= require('multer');
const {readCSVFile}= require('../util/index');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now()+'.xlsx');

    }
});
var upload = multer({storage: storage});
router.post('/fileUpload', upload.single('filename'),   async (req, res) => {
    readCSVFile();
    res.status(201).json({id:1});
});
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});

module.exports=router;
```

Utilty Code

```
const config = require('config')
const excelToJson = require('convert-excel-to-json')
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent')
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const json2xls = require('json2xls')
const fs = require('fs')
const awsConfig = {
    httpOptions: {
        agent: new HttpsProxyAgent(
            config.get('aws.proxy')
        ),
    }
}
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({
    profile: config.get('aws.profile'),
})
AWS.config.update(awsConfig)

let uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4')
let csv = [];

const lexRunTime = new AWS.LexRuntime({
    region: config.get('aws.region'),
})
let refreshId
const readCSVFile = () => {

    const csvSheet = excelToJson({
        sourceFile: './Test.xlsx',
    })
    csvSheet.Sheet1.forEach(element => {
        csv.push((element.A.slice(0, element.A.length)))
    })
    runTask()
    refreshId = setInterval(runTask, 1000)
}
let botParams = {
    botAlias: config.get('bot.alias'),
    botName: config.get('bot.name'),
    sessionAttributes: {},
}
const missedUtterancesArray = []
const matchedUtterancesArray = []
let start = 0
let end = 50
let count = 50

const runTask = () => {
    let itemsProcessed = 0
    console.log('executing...')
    const arrayChunks = csv.slice(start, end)
    arrayChunks.forEach((element) => {
        botParams.inputText = element
        botParams.userId = `${uuidv4()}`
        lexRunTime.postText(botParams, function (err, data) {
            itemsProcessed++
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack)
            else {
                if (data.intentName === null) {
                    missedUtterancesArray.push({
                        Utterance: element,
                    })
                }
                else{
                    matchedUtterancesArray.push({
                        Utterance: element,
                    })
                }
            }
            if (itemsProcessed === arrayChunks.length) {
                start = csv.indexOf(csv[end])
                end = start + count
            }
            if (start === -1) {
                let xls = json2xls(missedUtterancesArray)
                fs.writeFileSync('./MissedUtterances.xlsx', xls, 'binary')
                let matchedXls = json2xls(matchedUtterancesArray)
                fs.writeFileSync('./MatchedUtterances.xlsx', matchedXls, 'binary')
                console.log('File saved successfully!! ')
                console.log('Total Matched utterances count: ',csv.length-missedUtterancesArray.length)
                console.log('Total Missed utterances count: ',missedUtterancesArray.length)
                console.log('Total Utterances count: ',csv.length)
                clearInterval(refreshId)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: We can only help you if you show us the relevant code as the answer entirely depends upon what your code is doing.  Questions about code need to show us your code.

Comment: I don't see any exports in the utility code.  How is it loaded?  How is some function in it called?  How do you communicate with it?  Where are you expecting to use it in your REST route?  You need to give us a little more explanation here.

Comment: See, if your utility has to run before every or some endpoints, I will suggest you to write it as a middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I would have needed few more information to answer this but pardon my try if this does not work -

the ***setInterval*** method in the readCSVFile the reason. Being an asynchronous function, this will not stop the code progression.

***lexRunTime.postText*** also looks like asynchronous. I think you'd be better off with using promises while responding to the client.